# getting new json feed after clicking previous and next button on FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

on my FullCalendar implementation, I am using ajax to get a Json feed to of the list of events.  This works on the present month/year.

When I click the next/previous button I need to get a new Json feed of the list of events for the specified month/year.   How do I change that?  I have my onclick and my ajax call working but it is not populating the events.

Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var events = [];
    var thisMonth = $('#thisMonth').html();
    var thisYear = $('#thisYear').html();
    var theMonth;
    var theYear;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetEvents",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, evt) {
                events.push({
                    title: evt.Title,
                    start: evt.Start,
                    id: evt.ID
                });
            });
            GenerateCalendar(events);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.fc-prev-button', function () {
    //$('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
        alert('clicked previous');
        if (thisMonth == 1) {
            theMonth = 12;
            theYear = parseInt(thisYear) - 1;
        } else {
            theMonth = parseInt(thisMonth) - 1;
            theYear = thisYear;
        }
        alert(theMonth + '-' + theYear);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {Month: thisMonth,Year: thisYear,Direction: 'prev'},
            url: "/Home/GetPrevNextEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, evt) {
                    events.push({
                        title: evt.Title,
                        start: evt.Start,
                        id: evt.ID
                    });
                    $('#thisMonth').html(theMonth);
                    $('#thisYear').html(theYear);
                });

                calendar.prev();
                calendar.events = events;
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.fc-next-button', function () {
    //$('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
        alert('clicked next');
        
        if (thisMonth == 12) {
            theMonth = 1;
            theYear = parseInt(thisYear) + 1;
        } else {
            theMonth = parseInt(thisMonth) + 1;
            theYear = thisYear;
        }
        alert(theMonth + '-' + theYear);
       
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: {Month: thisMonth,Year: thisYear ,Direction: 'next'},
            url: "/Home/GetPrevNextEvents",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, evt) {
                    events.push({
                        title: evt.Title,
                        start: evt.Start,
                        id: evt.ID
                    });
                    $('#thisMonth').html(theMonth);
                    $('#thisYear').html(theYear);
                });
                calendar.next();
                calendar.events = events;
            }
        });
    });
    
    function GenerateCalendar(events) {
        
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                right: 'next',
                center: 'title',
                left: 'prev'
            },
            theme: false,
            timezone: 'local',
            editable: true,
            defaultDate: '@string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",thisDay)',
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            events: events,
            eventClick: function (calEvent) {
                window.location = '/MonthlyEvents/Details/' + calEvent.id;
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Quite simply, don't do it like this at all. Use the pattern fullCalendar has established for re-fetching events when the date range changes (which can be caused by [more things](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/date-navigation) than just pressing the prev/next buttons). You can have either a direct [json event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) or an [events function callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function) which gives you more flexibility so you can write your own custom ajax call.

Comment: But the important point is that in both of those patterns, you simply tell fullcalendar how to fetch the events, and then fullCalendar will automatically fetch new events whenever it needs to (e.g. because the date range or view has changed), and will provide the start and end dates of the new date range, so that your server / ajax call can filter and return the correct set of events. This is reliable, and means you don't have to mess about trying to handle button clicks yourself, or working out what the date range needed is. Always study the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: (Also, please make sure you're reading the documentation for the correct version of fullCalendar (as per my links above). You tagged the question with fullcalendar 4, but from the code you're clearly using fullcalendar 3 (as this was the last version which was implemented as a jQuery plugin).